# C using read() function to read strings per line

Tags: c

I'm currently working on an assignment and we have the task of using just system calls to manipulate a file. I'm very confused and stuck on how I would go about using the `read()` function in C to read strings in a file and store them somewhere. For example if I had the file:

```
John 100
Sarah 200
Alex 300
```

I would like to store the name and number into two different variables. Similar to how in `fscanf` you can read data from files into two variables. We aren't allowed to use structs or anything like that either.

I used this code to store the names and the values

```
        for (i = 0; strcmp(names[i], "") != 0; i++) {
            //Parses balance double into a char to store into .dat file
            snprintf(nums[i], 100, "%6.2lf", balances[i]);
            //Writing names to file
            write(fd, &names[i], strlen(names[i]));
            write(fd, " ", strlen(" "));
            //Writing balance to file
            write(fd, &nums[i], strlen(nums[i]));
            write(fd, "\n", strlen("\n"));
        }
```

and this was all I could think of for the reading part, resources on the read function are pretty limited.

```
        char str[100];
        char num[100];
        size_t bytes = sizeof(buf);
        fd = open("gifts2.dat", O_RDWR | S_IWUSR);
        read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("%s", buf);
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. What are you trying to fix?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to using fscanf but with read to store values from a file. For example, how in fscanf you're able to store the content in lines to variables by doing something like (file, "%s %d", str, &num). Not quite sure how to achieve that using read though..

Comment: start by reading in each line, loop reading one char at a time and look to see if it is a newline character

Comment: You can either read one character at a time, or you can read chunks. Either way, you need to check the return value from the `read` function, because that's how you know when you've reached the end of the file.

Comment: @Dieynaba "using the read() function in C to read strings" --> when should reading stop?  When it reads a `'\n'`, a `'\0'`, the <enter> key, fills the buffer or what?  Please specify what you mean by _string_.

Comment: Dieynaba, `size_t bytes = sizeof(buf);` --> where is `buf` defined?

Comment: Sorry buf isn't defined, I meant to replace it with str. The reading should stop once the end of file is reached meaning I've stored everything

Answer (score 2):

To read a text file with no particular structure with just system calls, the simplest approach is to read it one byte at a time:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int readchar(int fd) {
    for (;;) {
        unsigned char uc;
        switch (read(fd, &uc, 1)) {
          case 0:
            return EOF;
          case 1:
            return uc;
          default:
            if (errno != EINTR)
                return EOF;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use `readchar(fd)` like you would use `getc(fp)` and possibly write your own `readstring()` and/or `scanfd()` functions.

If the file has a fixed format, you can use `read` to read a block of structured data at a time and adjust the contents according to the local endianness and alignment constraints.

Note that your writing code seems incorrect:

- `write(fd, &names[i], strlen(names[i]));` should not use `&`. If `names` is an array of pointers, this will write the pointer values instead of what they point to, possibly invoking undefined behavior for strings longer than a few bytes.  Use this instead: `write(fd, names[i], strlen(names[i]));`
- same remark for `write(fd, &nums[i], strlen(nums[i]));`

The code may seem to work if `names` and `nums` are 2D `char` arrays, but dropping the `&` is also a correct fix in this case.